# How do you decide how much data to push to the user in Single Page Applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, web-applications, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

Say you have a Recipe Manager application that you're building with a Web Api project.  Do you send the list of recipes along with their ingredient names in JSON?  Or do you send the recipes, ingredient names, and ingredient details?  What's the process in determining how big the initial payload should be for a SPA?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are the determining factors in how much to send to the client in an initial page:

1. Data that will be displayed for that first page
2. Lookup list data for any drop downs on that page
3. Data that is required for and presentation rules (might not be displayed but is used)

On a recipe page that would show a list of recipes, I would get the recipes and some key factors to display (like recipe name, the dish, and other key info) that can be displayed in a  list. Enough for the user to make a determination on what to pick. Then when the user dives into a recipe, then go get that 1 recipe's details.

The general rule is get what you user will almost certainly need up front. Then get other data as they request it.

Comment: Thanks John.  I'm watching you on pluralsight right now (your SPA video) - incredible job.

Answer (score 6):

The process by which you determine how much data to send solely depends on the experience you want to provide your users - however it's as simple as this. If my experience demands that I readily display all of the recipes with a brief description and then allow them to drill into the recipe to get more information, then I'm **only** going to send enough information to produce the display and navigate further into the entity.

If then after navigating into the recipe it requires that you display the ingredient names and measures then send down that and enough information to navigate further into any single ingredient.

And as you can see it just goes on and on.

Comment: This also feels more restful. /recipes gives you your list of recipes (title, short description picture) and a pointer to the actual recipe at say /recipes/super-yummy-meatballs which then has ingredients, method, etc.

Answer (score 4):

It depends if your application is just a simple HTTP API backing your web page, or your goal is something more akin to Platform As A Service. One driver for the adoption of SPA is that it makes the browser another client, just like an iOS or Android app,or a 3rd party.

If you want to support multiple clients, then it's likely that you want to design your APIs around the resources that you are trying to expose, such that you can use the uniform interface of GET/POST/PUT etc. against that resource. This will means it is much more likely that you are not coding in an client specific style and your API will be usable by a wide range of clients.

A resource is anything you would want to have its own URN.

I would suggest that is likely that in this case you would want a Recipe Book resource which has links to individual Recipe resources, which probably contain all the information necessary for that Recipe. Ingredients would only be a separate resource if you had more depth on what an Ingredient contained and they had their own resource.

At Huddle we use a Documentation Driven Design approach. That is we write the documentation for our API up front so that we can understand how usable our API would be. You can measure API quality in WTFs. http://code.google.com/p/huddle-apis/

Now this logical division might not be optimal in terms of performance. Your dealing with a classic tradeoff (ultimately architecture is all about balancing design tradeoffs) here between usability of your API and the performance of your API. Usually, don't favour performance until you know that it is an issue, because you will pay a penalty in usability or maintainability for early optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Ian.  Question - in this context, is a PaaS just an API on steroids?  A web api built specifically for consumption by multiple clients (web/mobile/tablet/etc)?

Comment: Yes, PaaS could be seen as an API on steroids i.e. you are just building to target multiple (perhaps unknown to you) clients.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to implement the OData query support for WebAPI. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api

That way, your clients can perform their own queries to return only the data they need.